# how do you do a integer validation in C++?

Tags: c++

ok, I have been looking for days now but I cant find anything that will work.

I have a program and I want to make sure that the user enters a integer and not a double.

this program works fine but I need to validate  the numOne and numTwo to make sure they are integers and not doubles, (5.5)

```
            int main()
        {       //This is where my variables are stored
                int numOne, numTwo, answer, rightAnswer, ranNumOne, ranNumTwo;


                //this will display to the user to enter a range of numbers to be used
                cout << "Please enter a set of numbers to be the range for the problems." << endl;
                cout << "Please enter the beginning number." << endl;
                cin >> numOne;      
                cout << "please enter the ending number." << endl;
                cin >> numTwo;

                //this makes sure that the user entered a integer(if not the program will close)
                if (!(cin >> numOne)) 
                {
                    cout << "You did not enter a integer PLEASE RE-RUN THE PROGRAM AND TRY AGAIN!" << endl;
                    cin.clear();    
                    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                    exit(0);
                }

                cout << "please enter the ending number." << endl;
                cin >> numTwo;

                //this makes sure that the user entered a number(if not the program will close)
                if (!(cin >> numTwo)) 
                {
                    cout << "You did not enter a integer PLEASE RE-RUN THE PROGRAM AND TRY AGAIN!" << endl;
                    cin.clear();    
                    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                    exit(0);

                }

                //this is where the first number is generated       
                srand(time(0));
                ranNumOne = rand() % (numOne - numTwo) + 1;
                system("PAUSE");  

                //this is where the second number is generated
                srand(time(0));
                ranNumTwo = rand() % (numOne - numTwo) + 1; 

                //this is where the calculations are done
                rightAnswer = ranNumOne + ranNumTwo;

                //this displays the problem that was generated
                cout << "What is: " << endl;        
                cout << setw(11) << ranNumOne <<  endl;
                cout << setw(6) << "+" << setw(3) << ranNumTwo <<  endl;
                cout << "     -------\n";
                cin >> answer;

                //this checks to see if the answer is right or not and displays the result
                if (answer == rightAnswer)
                {
                    cout << "Your answer was correct! " << endl;            
                }
                else
                cout << "The correct answer is: " << rightAnswer << endl;



            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: I have tried many different things and nothing is working.

Comment: Your program asks for the numbers twice, once without checking and once with checking.

Comment: Users don't enter ints or doubles. They enter _numbers_. Those numbers are parsed as flexibly as possible given the type you're reading into.

Comment: it seams that I have to ienter the numbers 2 times to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Use `std:n:ci.fail()` to see if it failed.

```
int numOne;
cin >> numOne;
if(cin.fail())
    cout << "Not a number...")
```

Maybe even a nice template function.

```
template<typename T>
T inline input(const std::string &errmsg = "") {
    T var;
    std::cin >> var;
    while (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        std::cout << errmsg;
        std::cin >> var;
    }
    return var;
}
```

Or not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

#define DIFF(n1, n2) (n1 > n2 ? n1 - n2 : n2 - n1)

using namespace std;


int input(const string &firstmsg = "", const string &errmsg = "") {
    int var;
    std::cout << firstmsg;
    std::cin >> var;
    while (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cout << errmsg;
        cin >> var;
    }
    return var;
}


int main(){
    //This is where my variables are stored
    int numOne, numTwo, answer, rightAnswer, ranNumOne, ranNumTwo;


    //this will display to the user to enter a range of numbers to be used
    cout << "Please enter a set of numbers to be the range for the problems." << endl << endl;
    numOne = input("Please enter the beginning number: ", "Invalid. Enter again: ");

    //this asks the user for the second number
    numTwo = input("Please enter the ending number: ", "Invalid. Enter again: ");

    //this is where the first number is generated       
    srand(time(0));
    ranNumOne = rand() % (DIFF(numOne, numTwo)) + 1; // ensures it will always be positive
    system("PAUSE");

    //this is where the second number is generated
    srand(time(0));
    ranNumTwo = rand() % (DIFF(numOne, numTwo)) + 1;

    //this is where the calculations are done
    rightAnswer = ranNumOne + ranNumTwo;

    //this displays the problem that was generated
    cout << "What is: " << endl;
    cout << setw(11) << ranNumOne << endl;
    cout << setw(6) << "+" << setw(3) << ranNumTwo << endl;
    cout << "     -------\n";
    cin >> answer;

    //this checks to see if the answer is right or not and displays the result
    if (answer == rightAnswer){
        cout << "Your answer was correct! " << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "The correct answer is: " << rightAnswer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know, I know... It's cute though, isn't it?

Comment: Not really no. Why don't you write a nice function?

Comment: whats with the std::        does the program need that or can it be removed?    I am in c++ year 1

Comment: as well the program works  until the user inputs 5.5 which is a double not a integer It already validates the number I need to make sure that its an integer

Comment: @DannyArnold that specifies the namespace. You can remove it if you use `using namespace std;` in your program above.

Comment: why do I have to enter the number 2 times for it to work?

Comment: I should not have accepted the edit. That was an accident. You didn't even incorporate my solution. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: I tried what you put it didn't work, or I didn't understand it

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use srand twice like that. Really, you should use `std::random_device` in `<random>`.

Comment: I copied and pasted to a new program and the validation failed this is what I got when I ran it

Comment: Please enter a set of numbers to be the range for the problems.

Please enter the beginning number: 5.5
Please enter the ending number: Invalid. Enter again: 6.9
Press any key to continue . . . 
What is: 
          1
     +  1
     -------
The correct answer is: 2

Comment: im new to c++ so its all new to me... im trying all different things

Comment: but like I said the second code I put there works fine, but I have to input the numbers 2 times for the program to work

Comment: the second code makes sure that each variable is a integer and a number before it moves on. but when I enter the first number and hit enter it just sits there until I enter another number then it asks for the second number and I have to enter it 2 times

Comment: THANKS ALOT FOR THE - SCORE, I HAVE BEEN ASKING FOR HELP  AND ALL THAT I HAVE GOT WAS ERRORS........ ALL THE STUFF THAT WAS SENT TO ME HAS BEEN THROWING ERRORS AT ME..... I I WANTED WAS HELP WITH MY VALIDATION I DONT WANT TO CHANGE MY CODE TO A DIFFERENT STYLE, I JUST NEED TO VALIDATE THE USER INPUT TO MAKE SURE ITS AN INTEGER..... AND I GET SLACK.......THANKS

Answer (score 0):

why not, get the number into a double and then see if that double is an int. ie

```
double d;
cin>>d;
if (ceil(d) != d)
 cout >> " not an integer";
```

Comment: I don't know all kinds of fancy code, I know just  basic..... I also know that the code I have there works it just needs fine toned...I need to know why I have to enter the numbers 2 times and how to fix it... I like that I am getting help but advanced code wont help me right now.

Comment: this is as simple as it gets :-)

Comment: none of the stuff that has been posted here has worked, it is popping up with errors.

Comment: the code that I have works, but it requires the user to input the numbers 2 times....Why?